# Flutter error: xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations

Tags: flutter, ios15, xcode13

### Flutter version is 2.2.3 and I cant't run de flutter code on my iOS emulator.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           43.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:320795B7-1385-4044-B442-87A9808936D9, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    { platform:iOS, id:00008101-000825EC3AE1001E, name:leobidoous iPhone, error:Device is busy (Making leobidoous iPhone ready for development, Processing cache files from device, Making the device ready for development) }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
```

Comment: Have you tried building on a physical device? Or a different emulator version? What Xcode version is it using?

Comment: Is this after updating to Xcode 13?
I'm getting the same thing and the main change I made is updating Xcode, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Same here, have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem updating Xcode. Solve just logging back into Xcode.

1. Open Xcode
2. Open the project's Runner.xcworkspace file
3. Log into Xcode at: "Signing & Capabilities" -> "All" -> "Signing"

Item 3 was my problem. When updating Xcode, I was logged out.

Comment: Similar issue, I just needed to close and restart Xcode

Comment: It works for and this saves my time...

Answer (score 13):

Adding these lines to `Podfile` Helped me.

```
target.build_configurations.each do |build_configuration|
    build_configuration.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64 i386'
end
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: Don't know why I suddenly started getting this error but this solution worked! Thanks

Comment: This helped fix my issue as well! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you use package sign_in_with_apple, it should have 3.2.0 version at least.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution helped me too. But maybe just removing cache about sign_in_with_apple packge and let flutter pub and cocoapods gets it again would be a solution too. Note that, i didn't try it.

Answer (score 4):

The only solution that worked for me was to **completely remove the xcode** installed and **reinstall from the app store.**

When removing the old xcode, make sure to remove all the residual files - especially the developer folder.
*Try these following commands*

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

and remove xcode from **Application** to **bin**. Doing this will completely clean the xcode residuals and then you can reinstall from the appstore.

Answer (score 4):

put this code in your Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |build_configuration|
        build_configuration.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64 i386'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same issue and by running `flutter clean` fixed the issue for me.

Also try restarting the IDE if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I am fine after forcing the Simulator.app quit and run the command again.

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers here, depending on your circumstances, have aspects that absolutely remove this error.  For myself, what I can say is that I can confirm that using an 2021 M1 macbook pro max with a fresh set of tools, flutter 2.8.1, dart 1.15.1 and having the following or similar post_install section in my podfile also silenced the offending output.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT'] = 'dwarf'
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64 i386'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue for flutter version 2.5.1 stable
Previously i installed flutter using Zip archive file now I completely removed that installation and setup it using Git clone
[image: screenshot from flutter doc]

I did things like flutter clean, pod clear cache , pod install etc
**IMP Note** in xcode please check developer signing&capabilities options for runner etc
I did these and these are worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part here is

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

which means that any of the scripts configured in `Xcode > Targets > Runner > (Tab) Build Phases` failed. The problem here is that you do not see the error message (which script failed and why).

Add the `--verbose` flag (short: `-v`) to the `flutter run` command:

```
flutter run -v
```

This will output a lot. **At the end you need to scroll a bit up to the the actual script error.**

Once you know the actual error, you probably can solve it easily or open a new and more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error on flutter 2.5.3. Now I downgraded to 2.5.1 and the app is running on my iOS emulator. Try this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by clean the IDEA + `flutter clean` then restarting Mac then open Xcode from flutter project then clean Xcode build by select product -> Celan Build folder then RUN your project from Xcode to download dependence

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines to your podfile. Place the below lines in the post_install do [installer] section at the bottom of the Podfile.

Code :

```
target.build_configurations.each do |build_configuration|
  build_configuration.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64 i386'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This process will re-download ios and android development tools again after running the code through the ios and android simulator. Worked for me

> Flutter clean
>
> Flutter get
>
> Flutter channel stable
>
> flutter upgrade

and restart IDE as well as close Xcode. works for me, I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If your project is with firebase and it is cloned and cleaning is not well like me. Probably this can help you.

1. Add `GoogleService-Info.plist` back to your Runner project. (if already have can ignore)
2. Try to `Clean Build Folder` on xcode then `Build` again.
3. Try to build into `Simulator` using xcode.
4. Try to build into your connected `iPhone`.
5. If 3 and 4 is working. Back to your vscode then build and run again to `iPhone` or `Simulator`