# Flutter IOS xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:

Tags: ios, flutter

When I run the project directly in `xcode 13` everything works fine, but when compiling with `flutter run` I get this error, I already tried deleting the `DerivedData` files.
Lock the password keychain.
Deleting the Pods and all their files.
Deleting the WorkSpace.

But nothing turns out to be useful, I am from a mac m1 with Monterrey operating system, I would like to know if someone has a possible solution for this error that I have seen so recurrent

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter error: xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306519/flutter-error-xcodebuild-warning-using-the-first-of-multiple-matching-destina)

Answer (score 1):

Try following by running on specific device:

step1:- Run `flutter devices`, You will get list of devices connected. like this.

```
2 connected devices:

Redmi 4                   • 81cea4a7d740  • android-arm64 • Android 7.1.2 (API
25)
Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86   • Android 9 (API 28)
(emulator),
```

step2:- f you want to run in a specific device Run `flutter run -d Device name or Device id`
eg:- `flutter run -d Redmi` or `flutter run -d 81cea4a7d740`,

step3:- If you want to run in all devices than `flutter run -d all`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot