# Flutter php auto send data

Tags: php, flutter, dart, iot

I'm working in an IoT project, and I have data that cames from a sensor to my mobile application.

I'm wondering how to automatically send it to my mysql database.
Any ideas?

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306519/flutter-error-xcodebuild-warning-using-the-first-of-multiple-matching-destina. I think you might find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I have an idea.
You can make a simple post/put request by using state management.
Actually, it'll not work automatically.
but you can make an if-else condition or try-catch to post/put this data automatically to the server.