# Getting this warning when trying to run react native in iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode14

//within Xcode//
'value' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 12.0

//in terminal//
warning: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C [-Wstrict-prototypes]
static NSUInteger RCTDeviceTotalMemory()

the app running fine in android but cant able to run in iOS

i tried this approach mentioned below

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34106
[Flutter error: xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306519/flutter-error-xcodebuild-warning-using-the-first-of-multiple-matching-destina)
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36293

Answer (score 0):

Add to your Podfile this:

```
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5.0'
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.4'
  end
end
```