Ios Simulator Issue in Flutter
I'm not able to launch ios simulator for flutter apps.
Note the error faced below.
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BFD4B252-AFC0-4B7B-A46B-999999999999, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BFD4B252-AFC0-4B7B-A46B-999999999999, OS:17.0.1, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
    ** BUILD FAILED **

I have tried deleting Derived data folder , flutter Clean but no luck

Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306519/flutter-error-xcodebuild-warning-using-the-first-of-multiple-matching-destina

@SergeiNikitin Note that it has multiple solutions, and I have tried all of them.
target.build_configurations.each do |build_configuration|
build_configuration.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64 i386'
end
If you know any valid solution, let me know .
